# Find a triplet that sum a given value

Tags: c++, sum

I've been struggling with a problem where based on a given number i have to find all the triplets that sum gives the given number.

For example if the given number is `5` conditions are : (`x+y+z=5` and `x<=y<=z`) :

Input :

```
5
```

Output :

```
0 0 5
0 1 4
0 2 3
1 1 3
1 2 2
```

I've tried to find all the solutions starting with `0` but i can't figure out how to find solutions that start with `1`, `2`, `3`, etc

What i have so far :

```
int x,y,z;

void showSolutions(int c) {
    z=c;
    while((x<=y) && (y<=z)) {
        if((x<=y&&y<=z)&&(x+y+z)==c) {
            cout<<x<<" "<<y<<" "<<z;
            cout<<"\n";
        }
        y++;
        z--;
    }
}
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: Hint: if you have `x` and `y` such that `x + y <=5` then what must `z` be?

Comment: I'm not sure i understand but i guess z should be 5 - (x+y) ?

Comment: Yep! So maybe you could write a loop over all possible values of `x` (`for (int x = 0; x <= 5; x++)`), and a nested loop iterating over `y`s that satisfy to `x + y <= 5` in a similar way. Then `z` is determined for you!

Comment: These are called [integer additive partitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)). There are several highly optimized examples of algorithms floating around the web. Here are some examples in python by [Jerome Kelleher](http://jeromekelleher.net/tag/integer-partitions.html). In particular, these are called *restricted* partitions.

Comment: What Ben said, also the easiest way to enforce the `x<=y` condition is to start the nested loop from `y = x`...

Comment: I was able to solve it! Thanks for helping me!

Answer (score 0):

Well you can think of this recursively, let me try to point a generic method which would work for two numbers or triplets or more.

```
class sum
{
public:
    vector<vector<int>> triplets(int k, int target)
    {
        vector<vector<int>> result;
        vector<int> holder;
        getTriplets(k, target, holder, result);
        return result;
    }

    void getTriplets(int k, int target, vector<int>& holder, vector<vector<int>>& result)
    {
        if(target < 0) return;
        if(k < 0) return;
        if(k == 0 && target == 0) 
        {
            result.push_back(holder);
            return;
        }

        for(int i = 0; i <= target; ++i)
        {
            holder.push_back(i);
            getTriplets(k-1, target - i, holder, result);
            holder.pop_back();
        }
    }
};
```

You can invoke this as:

```
sum s;
auto res = s.triplets(3,5);
for(auto row : res)
{
    for(auto col : row) cout << col << " ";
    cout << endl;
}
```

where the first argument to triplets is the what the size of set required and the latter is the garget value. The problem here is, it will produce duplicates, `0 0 5` and `5 0 0` I will leave that for you to figure out how.

Simply add results to a temporary `holder` and recursively try all combinations. until you reach the target value which is `0` in our case since we are subtracting, or hit a error condition. Backtrack and pop the value and exhausting all combinations. Store the result if we hit the target.

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bd5742dea5daa079)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    int x,y,z;
    for(z=n;z>=0;z--)
    {
        for(y=0;y<=z && z+y<=n;y++)
        {
            x=n-(y+z);
            if(x<=y)
            cout<<x<<y<<z<<endl;
        }
    }
}
```

for n=5,you get

```
005
014
113
023
122
```